# Using EnumSet within an enum loaded by Hibernate: not an enum

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

I have this setup within a Spring Boot application:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id int id;
    @Enumerated MyEnum foo;
}

public enum MyEnum {
    FOO;

    private MyEnum() {
        EnumSet.of(this);
    }
}
```

I need the enum to use an `EnumSet`. When used in connection within a Hibernate `Entity`, the following error is thrown on application startup:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.example.enumdemo.MyEnum not an enum
    at java.util.EnumSet.noneOf(EnumSet.java:112) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.EnumSet.of(EnumSet.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.example.enumdemo.MyEnum.<init>(MyEnum.java:10) ~[bin/:na]
    at com.example.enumdemo.MyEnum.<clinit>(MyEnum.java:7) ~[bin/:na]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

([full output](https://pastebin.com/raw/FxsmARak))

Is there a way to fix this or can I not use `EnumSet` with Hibernate?

Comment: This is not a problem with hibernate, it is a problem with the way you use `Enum` and `EnumSet`. A small main method with `System.out.println(MyEnum.FOO);` throws the same exception. That means that you cannot create an `EnumSet` within the constructors of your enums themselves.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Should've tested that...